# pythonでscapyを使用してraw.loadの文字列を取得したい

Tags: python

#### 前提・実現したいこと

pythonでscapyを使用して受信されたパケットの内容を確認を行いたいのですが、
raw.loadがバイナリデータ？のためテキスト形式への変換を行いたいです。

#### python scapy ソースコード

```
from scapy.all import *
import scapy

def print_summary(pkt):
    if IP in pkt:
        ip_src=pkt[IP].src
        ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst
    if TCP in pkt:
        tcp_sport=pkt[TCP].sport
        tcp_dport=pkt[TCP].dport
    if (ip_src == "スニッフしたい該当IPアドレス") or (ip_dst == "スニッフしたい該当IPアドレス"):
        print pkt[Raw].load
```

#### pkt.show()で取得できるResponse内容

```
[ HTTP Response ]### 
              Status-Line= 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
              Accept-Ranges= None
              Age       = None
              E-Tag     = None
              Location  = None
              Proxy-Authenticate= None
              Retry-After= None
              Server    = 'Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0c PHP/5.3.8 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.10.1'
              Vary      = 'Accept-Encoding,User-Agent'
              WWW-Authenticate= None
              Cache-Control= None
              Connection= 'Keep-Alive'
              Date      = 'Mon, 12 Aug 2019 07:28:45 GMT'
              Pragma    = None
              Trailer   = None
              Transfer-Encoding= None
              Upgrade   = None
              Via       = None
              Warning   = None
              Keep-Alive= 'timeout=10, max=200'
              Allow     = None
              Content-Encoding= 'gzip'
              Content-Language= None
              Content-Length= '24'
              Content-Location= None
              Content-MD5= None
              Content-Range= None
              Content-Type= 'text/html'
              Expires   = None
              Last-Modified= None
              Headers   = 'Content-Length: 24\r\nContent-Encoding: gzip\r\nX-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent\r\nKeep-Alive: timeout=10, max=200\r\nServer: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0c PHP/5.3.8 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.10.1\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nDate: Mon, 12 Aug 2019 07:28:45 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html'
              Additional-Headers= 'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8\r\n'

[ Raw ]### 
                 load      = '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03+I-.\x01\x00\x0c~\x7f\xd8\x04\x00\x00\x00'
```

上記レスポンスの最下部の

```
load      = '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03+I-.\x01\x00\x0c~\x7f\xd8\x04\x00\x00\x00'
```

を変換したく、色々試したのですが、上手く行かないためご教授いただければ幸いです。
ちなみにサーバーからは「test」の文字が送信されています。

Comment: この辺りが参考になるかも。[Decode raw Scapy data to human readable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52260329/9014308), [Python's Scapy can't print load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44734309/9014308), [How to extract Raw of TCP packet using Scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27172789/9014308)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/205681

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Content-Encoding= 'gzip'
```

とあるようにgzip圧縮されているのでデコードしてやる必要があります。

以下はPython3.7、scapy2.4.3のREPLでのコード例です。

```
>>> sys.version
'3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]'
>>> load_layer("http")
>>> resp=HTTPResponse()/b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03+I-.\x01\x00\x0c~\x7f\xd8\x04\x00\x00\x00'
>>> data=gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(resp.load))
>>> data.read()
b'test'
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
上記の方法でテキスト取得が完了しました。